# ¿Cómo puedo hacer para que la apk que genero se instale en la memoria externa? Android Studio

Tags: android, manejo-de-memoria

Leí que con esta instrucción se podía hacer, pero no me funciona:

```
 android:installLocation="preferExternal"
```

**P.d.: La puse en el Manifest.**

Comment: [Android Studio](https://es.stackoverflow.com/tags/android-studio/info): Utilizar esta etiqueta solo si la pregunta está asociada al uso, funcionalidades o problemas con el IDE.

Answer (score 1):

Con los comandos de adb puedes configurar tu celular para que por defecto las apps se instalen en la memoria externa.

Sigue estos pasos y los haces desde la consola:

Primero encuentra dónde está el ejecutable de los comandos adb y te recomendaría colocar la ruta del adb.exe en tu variable de entorno para que lo puedas usar fácilmente.

Luego:

- Conectas tu celular por cable usb a tu laptop.
- Luego corres el comando adb devices (Para ver que celulares están conectados a tu laptop), el nombre de tu dispositivo estará en números y letras.

Ahora, el SO Android tiene un parámetro llamado setInstallLocation, por este parámetro le indicarás cómo quieres que se instalen las apps. setInstallLocation acepta 3 valores:

1.- 0[auto] -> El móvil escoge la mejor ubicación.

2.- 1[internal] -> Instala las apps en el almacenamiento interno.

3.- 2[external] -> Instala las apps en la tarjeta de memoria.

Ahora verificas la versión del SO de tu celular:

- Si es Android 4.0 o superior, ejecutas el siguiente comando:

  . adb shell pm set-install-location 2
- Si es Android 2.3 o inferior:

  . adb shell pm setInstallLocation 2

Y para comprobar el cambio ejecutas los siguientes comandos:

- Android 4.0 o superior

  . adb shell pm get-install-location
- Android 2.3 o inferior

  . adb shell pm getInstallLocation

Y listo, eso es todo.

Answer (score -1):

Lo que realizas es [correcto](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/data/install-location.html):

> Para permitir que el sistema instale su aplicación en el
>   almacenamiento externo, modifique su archivo de manifiesto para
>   incluir el atributo android: installLocation en el elemento
>   , con un valor de "preferExternal" o "auto". Por ejemplo:

```
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:installLocation="preferExternal"
    ... >
```

Pero es muy importante aclarar que **si tu dispositivo por alguna razón no cuenta con almacenamiento externo o el almacenamiento externo esta lleno, el sistema instalara la aplicación en el almacenamiento interno.**

Comment: **Cuando se califique con -negativo, es bueno para el sitio se indique la razón**, esto para mejorar la pregunta, eliminarla o si existen argumentos platicar sobre el tema.